# Error with spring bean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm

**UPDATE: ADD Maven dependecies**
**UPDATE: this error solved by adding maven depency  **

Good day.
I have this part of AplicationContext.xml

```
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="namingStrategy">
        <ref bean="namingStrategy"/>
    </property>
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <!--<value>genericdaotest/domain/Person.hbm.xml</value>-->
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Maven dep for spring and hibernate

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6</version>
        </dependency>


      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

But, when I start my Application, it said me this error

```
Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean] for bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean
```

But I am using hibernate4. What kind of magic does it? =)
I have already tried to redeploy app, but result is the same

Comment: Which version of Spring you are using? Can you post your maven dependancy?

Comment: Update. I use Intellij Idea 12, and add support frameworks spring and hibernate, so some jar files was added to lib folder of project

Comment: Try adding Spring ORM dependancy:
<artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>

Comment: May I suggest you to drop Spring? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219799/whats-the-benefit-of-spring-xml-ioc-over-java-instantiation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed the Spring-ORM module:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

[Check the packages list](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm/3.1.1.RELEASE), it contains the `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3` package and the class you need.

Also, I think the class is wrong, shouldn't it be the `hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean`? Are you using annotations? or XML?

Comment: It helps, THANK YOU very much, but took me another error: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider

Answer (score 0):

Change your session factory in the spring application context to use hibernate 4 as your maven dependency states.

org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean

and add the spring-orm dependency