# Create bean for sessionFactory in applicaionContext

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, javabeans

**UPDATE: Show full application context**

Good day.
I try to integrate spring and hibernate and tapestry, but have problems with some beans in application-context.xml
Here my pom.xml part with hibernate and spring.
I use IDE: Idea 12, with supporting of spring, tapestry and hibernate framework, so some jar file in lib directory.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6</version>
        </dependency>


      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Here my applicationcontext.xml, part for sessionFactry bean

```
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/reframework</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>root</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>root</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="namingStrategy"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.FieldRetrievingFactoryBean">
        <property name="staticField">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy.INSTANCE</value>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="namingStrategy">
            <ref bean="namingStrategy"/>
        </property>
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <!--<value>genericdaotest/domain/Person.hbm.xml</value>-->
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLMyISAMDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="extendedFinderNamingStrategy"
          class="com.packtpub.domain.finder.classes.ExtendedFinderNamingStrategy" />


    <!--  Dao Layer generic config-->
    <bean id="finderIntroductionAdvisor" class="com.packtpub.domain.finder.classes.FinderIntroductionAdvisor"/>
    <bean id="abstractDaoTarget"
          class="com.packtpub.domain.dao.ReDAO" abstract="true">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref bean="sessionFactory"/>
        </property>
        <property name="namingStrategy">
            <ref bean="extendedFinderNamingStrategy" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="abstractDao"
          class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean" abstract="true">
        <property name="interceptorNames">
            <list>
                <value>finderIntroductionAdvisor</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!--  Dao Layer instances -->
    <bean id="objectDao" parent="abstractDao">
        <property name="proxyInterfaces">
            <value>com.packtpub.domain.dao.objects.IObjectDAO</value>
        </property>
        <property name="target">
            <bean parent="abstractDaoTarget">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <value>com.packtpub.domain.entities.ObjectEntity</value>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

But, when I start my applicationt, it gives me an exception

```
Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider
```

as I understood after searching in hibernate 4 there is no such class, but what I need to do, to solve it?

Here full stacktrace

```
[DEBUG] AppModule.IObjectService Loading class com.packtpub.services.ObjectService.
[DEBUG] AppModule.IObjectService Marking class com.packtpub.services.ObjectService to be (re-)loaded
[DEBUG] AppModule.IObjectService BEGIN Analyzing com.packtpub.services.ObjectService
[DEBUG] AppModule.IObjectService   END Analyzing com.packtpub.services.ObjectService
[DEBUG] AppModule.IObjectService Invoking constructor public com.packtpub.services.ObjectService() (for service 'IObjectService')
[INFO] support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@5b905255: startup date [Tue Jan 08 21:05:19 MSK 2013]; root of context hierarchy
[INFO] xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
[INFO] support.DefaultListableBeanFactory Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@989472: defining beans [dataSource,namingStrategy,sessionFactory,extendedFinderNamingStrategy,finderIntroductionAdvisor,abstractDaoTarget,abstractDao,objectDao]; root of factory hierarchy
[INFO] datasource.DriverManagerDataSource Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
[INFO] support.DefaultListableBeanFactory Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@989472: defining beans [dataSource,namingStrategy,sessionFactory,extendedFinderNamingStrategy,finderIntroductionAdvisor,abstractDaoTarget,abstractDao,objectDao]; root of factory hierarchy
[ERROR] ioc.Registry Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider
[ERROR] ioc.Registry Operations trace:
[ERROR] ioc.Registry [ 1] Triggering event 'action' on Index:increment
[ERROR] TapestryModule.RequestExceptionHandler Processing of request failed with uncaught exception: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider
org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider [at classpath:com/packtpub/pages/Index.tml, line 19]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.logAndRethrow(OperationTrackerImpl.java:121)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:88)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:87)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1124)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementResourcesImpl.invoke(ComponentPageElementResourcesImpl.java:146)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.triggerContextEvent(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1053)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ComponentEventRequestHandlerImpl.handle(ComponentEventRequestHandlerImpl.java:81)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ImmediateActionRenderResponseFilter.handle(ImmediateActionRenderResponseFilter.java:42)
    at $ComponentEventRequestHandler_11e927111127.handle(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.AjaxFilter.handle(AjaxFilter.java:42)
    at $ComponentEventRequestHandler_11e927111127.handle(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$41.handle(TapestryModule.java:2476)
    at $ComponentEventRequestHandler_11e927111127.handle(Unknown Source)
    at $ComponentEventRequestHandler_11e9271110ae.handle(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ComponentRequestHandlerTerminator.handleComponentEvent(ComponentRequestHandlerTerminator.java:43)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.InitializeActivePageName.handleComponentEvent(InitializeActivePageName.java:39)
    at $ComponentRequestHandler_11e9271110b0.handleComponentEvent(Unknown Source)
    at $ComponentRequestHandler_11e92711107b.handleComponentEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ComponentEventDispatcher.dispatch(ComponentEventDispatcher.java:46)
    at $Dispatcher_11e92711107e.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at $Dispatcher_11e927111078.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$RequestHandlerTerminator.service(TapestryModule.java:302)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RequestErrorFilter.service(RequestErrorFilter.java:26)
    at $RequestHandler_11e927111079.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$3.service(TapestryModule.java:902)
    at $RequestHandler_11e927111079.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$2.service(TapestryModule.java:892)
    at $RequestHandler_11e927111079.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.StaticFilesFilter.service(StaticFilesFilter.java:90)
    at $RequestHandler_11e927111079.service(Unknown Source)
    at com.packtpub.services.AppModule$1.service(AppModule.java:98)
    at $RequestFilter_11e927111074.service(Unknown Source)
    at $RequestHandler_11e927111079.service(Unknown Source)
    at $RequestHandler_11e92711106d.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$HttpServletRequestHandlerTerminator.service(TapestryModule.java:253)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.gzip.GZipFilter.service(GZipFilter.java:53)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_11e92711106f.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.IgnoredPathsFilter.service(IgnoredPathsFilter.java:62)
    at $HttpServletRequestFilter_11e92711106b.service(Unknown Source)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_11e92711106f.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$1.service(TapestryModule.java:852)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_11e92711106f.service(Unknown Source)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_11e92711106a.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter.doFilter(TapestryFilter.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1822)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.tapestry5.runtime.ComponentEventException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider [at classpath:com/packtpub/pages/Index.tml, line 19]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.processEventTriggering(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1136)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.access$3100(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:61)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$5.invoke(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1057)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$5.invoke(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1054)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:74)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.packtpub.services.ObjectService.AddObject(ObjectService.java:27)
    at $IObjectService_11e92711112a.AddObject(Unknown Source)
    at $IObjectService_11e9271110ab.AddObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.packtpub.pages.Index.onActionFromIncrement(Index.java:61)
    at com.packtpub.pages.Index.dispatchComponentEvent(Index.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.dispatchEvent(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:927)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.processEventTriggering(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1112)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2562)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1427)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Introspector.java:1261)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1122)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:414)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:161)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<init>(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:224)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getCachedIntrospectionResults(BeanWrapperImpl.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyDescriptorInternal(BeanWrapperImpl.java:354)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.isWritableProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:430)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1362)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.CacheProvider
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 95 more
[INFO] AppModule.TimingFilter Request time: 714 ms
```

Comment: I still dont see datasoucse bean, also do you have a full stacktrace? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528862/exception-noclassdeffounderror-for-cacheprovider

Comment: include ehcache jar into your dependency........

Comment: This is a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219059/error-with-spring-bean

Comment: No, there was another error,that's why I create another question. Error messages are different.

Comment: did you include ehcache jar?

Answer (score 1):

Based on that exception, you have conflicting jars.  You haven't posted the full pom, but I see you mixed a spring 2.0 (spring-jdbc) with spring 3.1.1 jars.  You need to see the entire dependency tree and figure out where the conflicting hibernate jar is coming from.  Use the the following maven command to see the dependency tree: **`mvn dependency:tree`**

Comment: so, I made it, an it took me a big tree =) how can I found a problem?

Comment: you need to read it.  look for hibernate jars that don't match the 4.1.2.Final version you listed.  See how its being included and possibly exclude it.

Comment: how can I understood match it or not?